# React DOM updates on JS compile. But refreshing browser will give error 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, dom, use-effect

I use the following function:

```
const useApi = url => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = () => {
            axios
                .get(url)
                .then(response => {
                    setIsLoaded(true);
                    setData(response.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    setError(error);
                });
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [url]);

    const obj = {error, isLoaded, data}
    return obj
    //return { error, isLoaded, data}
}
```

And I call it with:

```
  const obj = useApi("http://localhost:1337/home")
```

The following is what `obj` returns:

```json
{
  "error": null,
  "isLoaded": true,
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "published_at": "2021-09-08T11:33:42.926Z",
    "created_at": "2021-09-08T11:33:41.281Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-09-08T11:33:42.943Z",
    "Een": [
      { "id": 1, "title": "asdasd", "content": "asdasd" },
      { "id": 2, "title": "asdasdas", "content": "asdas" },
      { "id": 3, "title": null, "content": null }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then I use display specific data with `obj.data.field`. This works perfectly. Then I add an index when using `obj` like `obj.data.field[0]`. After saving the file, React compiles it and because I use React's useEffect the DOM get's updated without refreshing the browser. The data is properly shown as it should. But as soon as I refresh the browser I get the following error:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')`

So getting data like `obj.data.field` works also when refreshing. But as soon as I add an index like `obj.data.field[0]` it only works when React compiles my code and the DOM updates. But then when I refresh the browser with the same compiled code I get the error.

Comment: btw, your `obj.data` could be invalid, because this is an async call, you need to do something like `obj.data ? "Show me the data" : "..."` in your display layer.

Answer (score 0):

You used setter functions / useEffect inside a pure function and it looks so weirdo.

take a look at an example I've get it ready for you

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = (url) => {
            axios
                .get(url)
                .then((response) => {
                    setIsLoaded(false);
                    setData(response.data);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    setError(error);
                });
        };
        fetchData("https://api.github.com/users");
    }, []);

    if (isLoaded) return <h1>Loading. . .</h1>;
    if (error) return <h1>Error. . .</h1>;

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <ul>
                {data &&
                    data.length > 0 &&
                    data.map(({ login }) => {
                        return <li>{login}</li>;
                    })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

*Hint:*  Try to use `Async Function` to make it more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've tried your code but still on DOM update it works but as soon refresh the page I get undefined.

Comment: But it works properply. take code to the codesnadbox.io to check out. I refreshed million times but the same result took place.